# Дубликат в другое поле с транслитом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, трансляция

Можно чуточку переделать скрипт, и сделать, чтоб при вводе в поле `<input type="text" id="input">` текста, дубликал шел в `<input type="text" id="input1">`, но с транслитом. А в `<input type="text" id="input">` оставался как есть?

```js
$('div#xfield_holder_input1').css('display', 'none');

var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.value = textTransform(this.value);
  $('#input1').val($('#input').val());
});

function textTransform(text){
  var arrru = [ 'Я','я','Ю','ю','Ч','ч','Ш','ш','Щ','щ','Ж','ж','А','а','Б','б','В','в','Г','г','Д','д','Е','е','Ё','ё','З','з','И','и','Й','й','К','к','Л','л','М','м','Н','н', 'О','о','П','п','Р','р','С','с','Т','т','У','у','Ф','ф','Х','х','Ц','ц','Ы','ы','Ь','ь','Ъ','ъ','Э','э', ' ' ];
  var arren = [ 'Ya','ya','Yu','yu','Ch','ch','Sh','sh','Sh','sh','Zh','zh','A','a','B','b','V','v','G','g','D','d','E','e','E','e','Z','z','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n', 'O','o','P','p','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','F','f','H','h','C','c','Y','y','`','`','\'','\'','E', 'e', '-' ];

  for(var i=0; i<arrru.length; i++){
    var reg = new RegExp(arrru[i], 'g');
    text = text.replace(reg, arren[i]);
  }
  
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо использовать `keyup` событие

```
$("#input").keyup(function() {
  $('#input1').val(textTransform($(this).val()));
});
```

Вот пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Функция запускается, когда пользователь отпускает клавишу в поле ввода. Функция выводит транслит в другое текстовое поле.</p>

Введите ваше имя: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<p>Меня зовут: <input type="text" id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").value = textTransform(x);
}
function textTransform(text){
  var arrru = [ 'Я','я','Ю','ю','Ч','ч','Ш','ш','Щ','щ','Ж','ж','А','а','Б','б','В','в','Г','г','Д','д','Е','е','Ё','ё','З','з','И','и','Й','й','К','к','Л','л','М','м','Н','н', 'О','о','П','п','Р','р','С','с','Т','т','У','у','Ф','ф','Х','х','Ц','ц','Ы','ы','Ь','ь','Ъ','ъ','Э','э', ' ' ];
  var arren = [ 'Ya','ya','Yu','yu','Ch','ch','Sh','sh','Sh','sh','Zh','zh','A','a','B','b','V','v','G','g','D','d','E','e','E','e','Z','z','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n', 'O','o','P','p','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','F','f','H','h','C','c','Y','y','`','`','\'','\'','E', 'e', '-' ];

  for(var i=0; i<arrru.length; i++){
    var reg = new RegExp(arrru[i], 'g');
    text = text.replace(reg, arren[i]);
  }

  return text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А куда вставлять?

Comment: так вроде понятнее

Comment: Все равно не понял, куда в этот код вставлять(

Comment: в ваш скрипт разумеется

Comment: А куда, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Заменить что-то, или вставить просто?

Comment: См. пример кода

Comment: А можно Без этого onkeyup="myFunction()" ? к сожалению у меня нет доступа к редактированию этого поля

Comment: можно, тогда надо использовать первоначальный вариант